# Getting common data from two different types of array

Tags: swift

```
struct Human{
    let name: String
    let id: String
    let travelled: String
}

struct Animal {
    let name: String
    let id: String
    let travelled: String
}

// Consider no human and animal object can have same name
let human1 = Human(name: "vikas", id: "12", travelled: "123")
let human2 = Human(name: "jacky", id: "15", travelled: "343")
let human3 = Human(name: "lucy", id: "32", travelled: "132")
let animal1 = Animal(name: "jacky", id: "56", travelled: "8979")
let animal2 = Animal(name: "lucy", id: "78", travelled: "678")
let animal3 = Animal(name: "jimmy", id: "98", travelled: "690")
let humans = [human1, human2, human3]
let animals = [animal1, animal2, animal3]

var list = [[String: String]]()
// can we eleminate this for loop with filter or something else
for human in humans {
    if let animal = animals.first(where: {$0.name == human.name}){
        let data = ["humanId": human.id, "animalId": animal.id]
        list.append(data)
    }
}
print(list)
```

**Output:**

```
[["humanId": "15", "animalId": "56"], ["humanId": "32", "animalId": "78"]]
```

Is there a way where we can apply multiple filter at a time to            get the desired output
   Unable to find or create one

Comment: I think protocols can help you here, just create one with the 3 parameters you need, and implement it in both structs. Or change struct to class and use inheritance, and at the end the common data will be the base class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using **`compactMap(_:)`** instead.

```
let list = humans.compactMap { (human) -> [String:String]? in
    if let animal = animals.first(where: { $0.name == human.name }) {
        return ["humanId": human.id, "animalId": animal.id]
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solutions still uses a loop but it will find multiple matches if such exists

```
animals.forEach {animal in
    let filtered = humans.filter { $0.name == animal.name }
        .map { human -> [String: String] in ["humanId": human.id, "animalId": animal.id] }

    list.append(contentsOf: filtered)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here it is

```
for index in 0..<humans.count {
    list[index]["humanId"] = humans[index]
    list[index]["animalId"] = animals[index]
}
```

Comment: Yes, it will crash. so can use min(humans.count, animals.count)                              or compare index with animals.count

Comment: And this does not answer the question as well.