# Is there an high order function for kotlin for getting common data from two different type of list?

Tags: android, kotlin, higher-order-functions

I have the same problem as described in this link(but it is in swift)
[Getting common data from two different types of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58745405/getting-common-data-from-two-different-types-of-array?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I have tried :

```
 val list=ArrayList<Model>()
 val list1=ArrayList<Model1>()
 val hashMap=Hashmap<Int,Int>()
 for (i in list.indices) {
       val data = list1.filter { it.name == list[i].name }
        if (data.isNotEmpty()) {
        hashMap.put(data[0].id,list[i].id)
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Based on the comment below, here's a way to do it without iterating with the predicate twice:

```
val map = list.mapNotNull{el -> 
        list1.firstOrNull{el1 -> el.name == el1.name}?.let{el1 -> el.id to el1.id}
    }.toMap()
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-not-null.html should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [intersect](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/intersect.html) to retrieve common items between two lists:

```
val l1 = listOf<Int>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
val l2 = listOf<Int>(1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
println(l1.intersect(l2))
```

All you need to do it's to define the equality between two items:

```
class A(val name: String) {
    override operator fun  equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (other is B)
            return this.name == other.anotherFieldForName
        return false
    }
}

class B(val anotherFieldForName: String)


val l1 = listOf<A>(A("Bob"), A("Alice"), A("Margoulin"))
val l2 = listOf<B>(B("Bob"), B("Margoulin"))
println(l1.intersect(l2))
println(l2.intersect(l1))
```

Comment: This will work if object in both array are primitive type but  here I have two different model  and number of keys inside the models are different .

Comment: I validated my answer before the end... Sorry for that. I added an example with two different types of list

Comment: But I have two  data model class with primary constructor only and keys are initialized through primary constructor.